# What is multi-fold argument ? please can you explain with examples?

Tags: legal-terms, legal-concepts

What is multi-fold argument ? please can you explain with examples?

Does multi-fold argument mean multiple stages of proof, where one ends at a stage if the stage is sufficient to prove what is to be proved ? for example, Is the below case a multi-fold argument ?

The is a college C that has the following rules:-

1. Students will not be allowed to enter college it they are late to college.
2. Students will not be allowed to enter exam hall if they do not have the hall ticket.
3. Students will not be allowed to given the exam question paper if they are not wearing formal shoes.

Student S is late and is without his hall ticket, but is wearing formal shoes. The professor refuse to give him the exam question paper.

When the professor is asked to explain his actions, he says the following:-

1. S is late; and
2. S does not the hall ticket; and
3. even if S is allowed into the college, S would not be allowed in the hall because he does not have a hall ticket.

Is the professor's explanation a multi-fold argument ?

Tks in advance
jo

Comment: "multi-fold theory" is a physics thing, not law, and has nothing to do with your argumentation. It's a model for Spacetime and gravitation.

Comment: "Mutifold argument" is not a legal term as far as I can tell, nor indeed a specific term in asny field. The def of "multifold" is given as "*numerous and varied; greatly diverse; manifold*" by  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/multifold_

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a legal term or a legal issue, and so is off-topic. It could fit on ELL.SE

Answer (score 3):

A multi-fold argument is one that has multiple independent grounds upon which a decision can be reached.

The distinction between such arguments and arguments based upon a single ground is important in the doctrine of collateral estoppel because it impacts which basis of a court decision can be considered judicially determined in a later lawsuit involving some of the same parties.